# ui.Select does not trigger the callback function when its items are updated

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

The code below shows how `sel1` updates `sel2` based on its value.

```js
var dict = {
  'a': {
    'foo': 321 
  },
  'b': {
    'foo': 123
  }
};

// Callback functions
var updateSel2 = function(k) {
  var sel2Items = Object.keys(dict[k]);
  
  sel2.items().reset();
  
  sel2Items.forEach(function(item) {
    sel2.items().add(item);
  });
  
};

var sel2Behavior = function(v) { print(v) };

// Selectors
var sel1 = ui.Select({
  items: Object.keys(dict),
  onChange: updateSel2
});

var sel2 = ui.Select({
  onChange: sel2Behavior
});

print(sel1);
print(sel2);
```

When `sel2` is updated for the first time, the `sel2Behavior` function works perfectly.

When I change the value of `sel1` again, since `sel2` will have the same value (`foo`), the callback function does not work.

What could be the reason? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of updateSel2, call setValue() to reset the value to null (with trigger = false)

```
sel2.setValue(null, false)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/99ecc23528a8c676c8ebd11dd69a183b